# Android ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent crashes before returning to app

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to receive the URI of an image taken via the Mediastore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent, but for some reason the default camera app (Google+) crashes before it even gets back to my activity and before my code reaches onActivityResult(). I suspect it has something to do with the way i'm crafting the intent, but i'm not sure. Here's my code:

```
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "New", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    });
```

If requested I can also add my onActivityResult code, though I'm not sure it's relevant here.

Here's the data from logcat:

> 12-02 10:47:43.976  26437-26437/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       Process: com.google.android.apps.plus, PID: 26437
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A source URI must be specified via the Intent's data field.
>               at dot.a(PG:185)
>               at com.google.android.apps.photoeditor.fragments.PlusCropActivity.onCreate(PG:93)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Is this because of the way im launching the intent? Is there a way to keep this intent from trying to crop the photo, as im handling cropping in a separate intent?

**Solution (I edited the code submitted by OferM):**

```
try
{
      tempFile = File.createTempFile("my_app", ".jpg");

      File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
      File image = File.createTempFile("my_app", ".jpg",storageDir);
      uri = Uri.fromFile(image);
}catch(Exception e){}

alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "New", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          takePictureIntent.putExtras(getIntent().getExtras());
          takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
          startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      }
});
```

Comment: If would be helpful to see Logcat.

Comment: I spent some time just now figuring out where to find the logcat issue, as filtering to just my app was not giving any relevant data.I'll update the post momentarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "New", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);

            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    });
```

where `uri` is the local path you want your image to be stored in. For example:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("my_app", ".jpg");
fileName = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
```

Comment: To elaborate on this a bit, you're not providing the picture intent with a file path to store the camera's image in. This details it nicely: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: Feeding this file into the intent makes the picture intent no longer crash, however the picture intent never returns to my app. onActivityResult does not get called unless I cancel the intent via the back button. I've also verified that the Uri going into the intent is not null.

Comment: I put my edited version of your response in the original post. I had to add a directory to get it to work. Thanks!